# Remove all symbols except Dot and also remove everything inside braces

Tags: php, regex

I creating seo friendly url permalinks , I have words like below which contains extra spaces , symbols etc.

**INPUT examples:**

```
software version 1.2.33 !##$%@~_+:";,|}{[];,;#&*^{2014}
Вася Обломов - Многоходовочка! (2014) MP3 [bitsnoop]
Дельфин - Андрей $$ (2014) MP3 [bitsnoop]
Laidback Luke & Uberjak'd – Go (Original Mix) [Hysteria] [bitsnoop]
Bob Dylan - Down In The Groove [320k MP3] [bitsnoop]
```

**Desired OUTPUT:**

```
software version 1.2.33
Вася Обломов Многоходовочка MP3
Дельфин Андрей MP3
Laidback Luke Uberjakd Go
Bob Dylan Down In The Groove
```

What i Tried :

```
$string = "ABC (Test1) hello$";
$string = preg_replace("/\([^)]+\)/","",$string); // 'ABC hello$'
$string = preg_replace("/[^ \w]+/", "", $string);
```

So in simple words i need to remove everthing inside brackets like `{}[]()` ,and remove all symbols except `. (dot)` .

P.s : this contains utf8 encoded strings aswel

Comment: Basically, remove `/{...} | (...) etc | [^\w.]/`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the below regex and then replace the matched characters with empty string.

```
 *(?:\{[^}]*\}|\[[^\]]*\]|\([^)]*\)|[^\p{L}\p{N}\s.])
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/bM4vP1/2)

**Code:**

```
$string = <<<EOT
software version 1.2.33 !##$%@~_+:";,|}{[];,;#&*^{2014}
Вася Обломов - Многоходовочка! (2014) MP3 [bitsnoop]
Дельфин - Андрей $$ (2014) MP3 [bitsnoop]
Laidback Luke & Uberjak\'d – Go (Original Mix) [Hysteria] [bitsnoop]
Bob Dylan - Down In The Groove [320k MP3] [bitsnoop]
EOT;
echo preg_replace('~ *(?:\{[^}]*\}|\[[^\]]*\]|\([^)]*\)|[^\p{L}\p{N}\s.])~u', '', $string)
```

**Output:**

```
software version 1.2.33
Вася Обломов Многоходовочка MP3
Дельфин Андрей MP3
Laidback Luke Uberjakd Go
Bob Dylan Down In The Groove
```

`\p{L}` matches any kind of letter from any language and `\p{N}` matches any kind of number.